# Get the key of a specific variable inside a Object to string in typecript/javascript

Tags: typescript, dynamic, tostring, typeof, keyof

I want to access an object dynamically like object[variableName] and not object["actual name of variable"].

Okay. lets say I have an object that looks like this:

```
export class Object {
  "key": string;
  "name": string;
  "address": string;
}
```

I would like to access this object dynamically with it's properties. I need to get the string of a specific name inside object like "key"/ "name" or "address". I do not want to get them all with typeof Object, not what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a dynamic way to access these keys, like below:

```
export function (item: Object, key: string): keyof Object | string{

}
```

in order to then access the objects variable like following:

```
const object: Object;
const variableName = getVariableName(object, object.test); // i want it to return "test". 

object[variableName] = null;
```

I don't want to access it like object["test"]. because it has to be dynamic.

I know how to do this for a simple variable and not a object:

```
let myVar = 'something';
let nameObject = {myVar};
let getVarNameFromObject = (nameObject) => {
  for(let varName in nameObject) {
    return varName;
  }
}
let varName = getVarNameFromObject(nameObject);
```

but this only works for {myVar} not for {object.test}

help me out :)

I tried different keyof typeof in methods but I can't figure it out.

### UPDATE

This is what I found, I am not very satisfied with this solution though:

```
const key = getKey<TextboxQuestion>(({key}) => null);

export var getKey = <T>(fn: (object: T) => null): string => fn.toString().match(/{([^;]*)}/)[1].replace(' ', '');
```

why this kindof works is because key it promises that key exists in Textboxquestion and it does, if I write something that doesn't exist in textboxquestion it throws compile error. but I don't want to say its a textboxquestion either :D I want that to be discovered somehow.

Comment: This is very Heavy [XY Problem you've given us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  You have a problem **X** and instead of asking us, "I have this problem".  You instead have provided **Y** which is your attempted solution that doesn't work and want us to fix that.  Instead you should say I have problem **X** I'm attempting to solve it using **Y** but it's not working, how do I solve for X (maybe using Y maybe not).